# How do I update a MySQL entry if I have a duplicate of the 'WHERE' fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, key, duplicates

I have the table with two fields - userId and something

I have this query:

```
INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$userId', '$something')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE something='$something'
WHERE userId='$userId'
```

Why is this not working? If I remove the

```
WHERE userId='$userId'
```

then it works but it updates all rows, and I obviously don't want to update the same info for every userId.

The `userId` field is set as UNIQUE in the database.

Comment: `INSERT ... VALUES ... WHERE ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`, the order is important (so NOT `INSERT ... VALUES ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... WHERE ... `)

Comment: Explain what you mean by *not working*.

Comment: Let me guess: you are getting a message that goes like this: *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near [something]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because your syntax is wrong.

The right syntax is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (col1, col2, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, ...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE non_key_col1 = newValue1;
```

**There's no `WHERE` involved.**

Please read the [MySQL reference for `insert... on duplicate key update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

---

Quoting from the link I provided above:

> If you specify `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a **`UNIQUE`** index or **`PRIMARY KEY`**, MySQL performs an `UPDATE` of the old row.

Comment: Is there any workaround to this? I need it, I don't want to update all the rows, just the one with the corresponding userId.

Comment: @ToniPerić Have you read the link I provided? This address your needs perfectly!

Comment: This is great, basically all I had to do **is** remove the "WHERE ..." from the sql query I've been performing in the first place.

Many thanks, Barranka!

Comment: @ToniPerić Please, keep a copy of (or a link to) the MySQL reference manual. If something doesn't work as you expect, look for the right syntax and try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO users1 VALUES ('$userId', '$something')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE something=
IF(userId='$userId','$something',something)
```